# Copy one string to another

Tags: c

I have a problem passing text to structure member. 
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int rank;
    int weapons;

}player;

player create_player(char name[], int rank, int weapons);
void display_player(player data);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    player tmp = create_player("First", 3, 3);
    display_player(tmp);
}

player create_player(char name[], int rank, int weapons)
{
    player newobj;
    char *tmp = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);

    strcpy(newobj.name, tmp);
    newobj.rank = rank;
    newobj.weapons = weapons;
    free(tmp);
    return newobj;
}

void display_player(player data)
{
    printf("Player name %s\n", data.name);
    printf("Player rang %d\n", data.rank);
    printf("Player weapons %d", data.weapons);
}
```

And here is the output

```
Player name 
Player rang 3
Player weapons 3
```

As you can see the result of "Player name" is empty. 
Also can you give me more elegant way to asign text to newobj.name ?
What I miss ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `strcpy` in your code is wrong (it copies uninitialized data into unallocated memory). You probably want:

```
newobj.name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
strcpy(newobj.name, name);
```

Or more simply, if you have `strdup`:

```
newobj.name = strdup(name);
```

Comment: thanks. It works. Do I need to free malloc() or it is released automatically ?

Comment: @user1089415 You need to free, **after you stop using it**. So you can't call free before `printf`.